# In "Starship" (also known as "Non-Stop), what was the name of the starship?

Tags: non-stop-novel

In the novel [*Starship* by Brian Aldiss](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/384579.Non_Stop) (more commonly known as *Non-Stop*), what was the name of the titular multi-generational starship?

Comment: Uh, how is any of this a spoiler for anything?

Comment: @Martha It's not clear at the beginning of the novel that it takes place on a ship.

Comment: @Martha the entire book has a "twist" ending... the fact it is on a ship at all is a secret that you discover as you read and is much of the reason the book is so awesome.

Comment: @Buzz - The book was released under the title "Starship" in several markets. The fact that it's set on a generational ship is no spoiler.

Comment: http://brianaldiss.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/brian-aldiss-non-stop-3.jpg

Comment: @Val .. it was released as Starship in 1 country and only once in the entire life of its publication.. everyone knows it and reads it as Non-Stop.

Comment: Only a moron wouldn't recognise that they're on a ship

Comment: @aJynks - That's not true. It was released repeatedly as "Starship", "The Starship", "Non-stop Cruise", "Travel Without End", etc etc

Comment: Better? Since it was released as Starship, we could perhaps reference that instead.

Comment: Nice question!!

Comment: And to be fair, although the copy I read was Non-Stop, the spoiler was on the jacket.

Answer (score 6):

The ship in question was called **Big Dog**, named in reference to the star that it was aimed toward, [Procyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procyon).

> *‘When this ship, “Big Dog” – so christened in jocular allusion to the
>   constellation Little Dog for which it set out – was detected in
>   Earth’s telescopes, finally returning from its long journey, everyone
>   on Earth was, as you say – happy, excited, marvelling.’ Fermour
>   paused. This event had taken place before he was born, but the epic
>   had often been retold to him. ‘Signals were sent out to the ship,’ he
>   continued; ‘they were never answered. Yet the ship kept speeding on
>   towards Earth. It seemed inexplicable. We have passed the
>   technological phase of our civilization, but nevertheless factories
>   were speedily built and a fleet of little ships launched towards “Big
>   Dog”. They had to find out what was happening aboard.*

The control facility for the ship (on Earth) was named **Little Dog**.

> *‘It’s not my doing,’ Fermour said hastily, scenting trouble. ‘It’s
>   just that this situation is too formidable for any of you. The ship is
>   in an orbit round Earth, and there it must stay. That was the edict of
>   the World Government which set up the Little Dog authority to control
>   this ship.’*

Answer (score 5):

Really stretching my memory here cos decades since I read it and I can't find a link to support my answer.

I think (aargh!) that it was called Big Dog